# How to check Facebook Login with FBLoginView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using `FBLoginView` to login to Facebook.

How do I check whether the user is logged in on the next launch?

I want the check to happen at the application level and not in a UIViewController like in the Facebook Tutorial on their Developers site.

If there is no way, then how can I add a Facebook Image which looks like a FBLoginView image to my custom button? Where can I find that image?

Comment: Improved grammar to make the question easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 delegate methods of FBLoginView

```
-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView

-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView
```

The first method would inform you whether the user is logged out and the second method would inform you whether the user is logged in and you can perform your action on the basis of that.

For getting the image of the Profile picture u can use users id or objectID  from this delegate method which contains all the user information.

```
-(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
{        
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=normal",user.id]];
    NSData  *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *profileImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
}
```

where the profileImage would contain the user profile Image and you can use that image to show on your custom button.

Comment: Actually, I know about those methods. But they work in Application level? Do I need to use them in AppDelegate file to check those methods when login? Do those methods called even we don't add FBLoginView as subview ? because, its in my sign in view and the next launch, I don't want to show that sign in screen. So, I dont get those methods access as they are in UIViewController level. I am in a confusion to use them in Application Level. :(

Comment: yes u have to use them in AppDelegate to take appropriate action as those methods are called even if not added in subview.If first method is called then show user sign in screen and if second method called then show your desired view controller.